# Chrome Extension: How to structure extension to have a producer (downloads data) and consumers content pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am very new to Chrome extensions and I have still to grasped the subtleties of the various types of pages that are available.

First of all, this extension is part of a research project, so it doesn't need to be perfect, just do what it needs to do.

Explanation of the extension's functionality:

The extension is for displaying images on certain pages with specific tags. The images are downloaded (from a well-known server) based on the settings in the user's profiles. These images need to be stored with some meta-data and when certain pages with right tags are detected by the content script, the image is inserted into the page for display. As the number of images in stock goes down, the background or event page have to request images. When users click on the images, that needs to be reported to he server.

I know that only content pages can modify the page being viewed. What I am not quite sure is on the best way to maintain a central supply of images, so the content scripts can draw from them.

One idea was to have an event page accepting messages from content script and reply with images. Now how would this event page check if it does not have enough images? Should it be a background page or can it be done in another way?

Am I going on about the right way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you've got a exhaustible pool of images on the event page, such as an array of images, then you can simply check whether the size of the list drops below a certain value. When this happens, refresh your stock by creating a request to the remote server.

Comment: @RobW but what happens when he event page is unloaded? or is it reloaded every time an event is passed to it? If that is so, I could do a check every time a content script consumes an image from the pool. Is that correct?

Comment: As you've phrased the question, it seems that the content script always pings the event page (through `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`), which will cause a closed event page to be reloaded. The script on the event page will check the size of the existing stock, and request new content while the event page is still alive.

Comment: @RobW Well, I proposed the only solution I saw. My actual question is: Is this a sensible way of achieving the functionality that I want the extension to have?

Comment: Your current concept looks viable. Though if the content are plain JavaScript objects, it might make more sense to use the `chrome.storage.local` (available to content scripts) to read data, and only send a message to the event page when new data is needed (Make sure that the event page only initializes a new request for content when no existing request is pending). If you're using event pages, you had to use either `chrome.storage` or `localStorage` to save preferences anyway, because event pages unload after a period of inactivity.